# List of Variables in Python

Tags: python

I'm attempting to write some Python code to create text boxes in Scribus, then group the text boxes.  I'm having some difficulty wrapping my brain around how to use lists or dictionaries to avoid a variable problem.

I have code to create a series of text boxes, then set the text.

```
shpA = scribus.createText(strLeft, strTop, strWidth, strHeight)
scribus.setText(strTextA, shpA) 
shpB = scribus.createText(strLeft, strTop, strWidth, strHeight)
scribus.setText(strTextB, shpB) 
shpC = scribus.createText(strLeft, strTop, strWidth, strHeight)
scribus.setText(strTextC, shpC)
```

Once the text boxes are complete, I group them on the page.

```
lstObjects=[shpA, shpB, shpC]
scribus.groupObjects(lstObjects)
```

Here's the problem.  I need to generate multiple shpA text boxes by looping through a variable number of iterations, then run the grouping.

```
icnt = 0
while icnt < (intNumLines):
    shpA = scribus.createText(strLeft, strTop, strWidth, strHeight)
    scribus.setText(strTextA, shpA) 
    icnt += 1
```

I've been able to run the loop and generate the boxes.  However, I haven't figured out how to assign distinct variable names to each text box (shpA1, shpA2, etc.).  As a result, only the last text box from the loop gets a variable (shpA), and I'm unable to reference the other text boxes generated within the loop.

I've read dozens of threads on lists and dictionaries, but I'm afraid all of this is a little advanced for me at this point.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need them to have distinct names? Could you not simply create a list of the objects and reference them by index?

Comment: Lists are absolutely critical to understand.  You need to know how to avoid doing what you're trying to do.  I would recommend starting at the python tutorial.  Start here with strings (the lists section builds on this) - https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A container (list or dict) is absolutely the only way to go, and far from complicated.  E.g, chance your loop to

```
icnt = 0
shpAS = []  # empty list to start
while icnt < (intNumLines):
    shpA = scribus.createText(strLeft, strTop, strWidth, strHeight)
    scribus.setText(strTextA, shpA) 
    icnt += 1
    shpAS.append(shpA)  # add new textbox at the end of the list
```

Now, `shpAS` is the list of text boxes each created as `shpA`.  Wherever you'd like (if you could generate a new variable each time) to use `shpA1`, use instead `shpAS[0]`; wherever `shpA2`, `shpAS[1]`; and so forth, it's really just as trivially simple as just using many separate "scalar" variables (as is apparently your heart's desire) could possibly be.

Comment: Thanks, Alex.  This got me headed in the right direction.  Works like a charm now.

Comment: @Jed, tx for letting me know, always happy to help!